# How to fix base table catalog_category_flat_store_6 doesn't exist in magento?

Tags: magento

How to fix base table catalog_category_flat_store_6 doesn't exist in magento?

Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'magentodb.catalog_category_flat_store_6' doesn't

exist

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to run **Catalog Category Flat Reindex**.

You can do this from the Magento backend: **System** -> **Index Management**
or via ssh.

Using SSH go to you shell directory and run `php -f indexer.php -- -reindex catalog_category_flat`